# C# call function from async false result

Tags: c#, xamarin, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've written a Xamarin.Forms Application that connects to an ESP32 via Bluetooth. Now I'd like to run the test() function from the MainPage.xaml.cs file from an async function.

I've tried it like that:

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test();
    }

    public void test()
    {
        service.toast.toastSuccess(JoystickControl.Xposition.ToString());
    }
    
}
```

Now I'd like to get the JoystickControlElement from the following Async Function:

```
class Bth : IBth
{

    public Bth()
    {
    }
    
    public void Start(string name, int sleepTime = 200, bool readAsCharArray = false)
    {
        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            service.toast.toastError("1");
            // Code to run on the main thread
        });
        Task.Run(async () => loop(name, sleepTime, readAsCharArray));
    }


    private async Task loop(string name, int sleepTime, bool readAsCharArray)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var mainPage = new Views.MainPage();
                mainPage.test();
            });
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

    }
  }
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public static Bluetooth.IBth bth = new Bluetooth.Bth();
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new mecanumWheelRobot.Views.MainPage();
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        bth.Start("mecanumWheelRobot", 200, false);
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
    }
}
```

When I call the test() function from the button click I get the correct value of the customcontrol and if i call it from the async I alwas get 0 in the toast message. What is the mistake?

Comment: Why is `loop` an async method if it doesn't await anything?  I think you need to spend some time learning [what async/await actually is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) before using it.

Comment: There are async but I've deleted them because they are not relevant here to solve the problem

Comment: you posted the same thing an hour ago.  Please do not post duplicates

Comment: this might be a good read too. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-with-async-await/

Comment: as I pointed out in your other question, the code in `loop` is not doing anything useful and has many problems.  Just repeatedly creating new instances of `MainPage` and calling `test` is not accomplishing anything.

Comment: @Jason - thanks for your answer. How should I do it then?

Comment: I have no idea what you are actually trying to do.  But don't use `while(true)`, and don't use `Thread.Sleep`.  If you wan to do something at a regular interval, use `Timer`.  If you want to access the currently active page, use `App.Current.MainPage`.  Simply creating a `new MainPage()` just creates a new instance in memory, it does not give you access to the existing instance that is displayed to the user.